# Less CSS - access part of class name and use in mixin

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, less

In Less, is it possible to access part of a class name and use within a mixin?

This will be best explained with an example:

I have a grid which i have declared as follows:

```
.columns (@columns) {
    //code here to generate column widths
}

//This is where my problem is:
.column-1 {
    .col (1)
}
.column-2 {
    .col (2)
}
.column-3 {
    .col (3)
}
// etc etc
```

Obviously there is a lot of repetitive code going on here.  Ideally i would like to be able to not have to declare column-1 column-2 etc and have some way, regex perhaps, of parsing the class name, and using the value after the dash to automatically calculate the column width.  I am almost certain twitter bootstrap is doing something similar but i cant understand it:

```
.spanX (@index) when (@index > 0) {
      (~".span@{index}") { .span(@index); }
      .spanX(@index - 1);
    }
    .spanX (0) {}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll understand that :

```
.columnX (@index) when (@index > 0) {          // Guarded mixin: use this mixin when the condition is true (like an if statement)
    (~".column-@{index}") {                    // outputs .column-0 as a class name
        .col(@index);                          // for the contents, use the col mixin
    }    // which class you are doing

    .columnX(@index - 1);                      // Recursive call to the same mixin, going down by 1
}
.columnX (0) {} // Default implementation so that when .columnX(0) is called, a matching mixin is found.

.col (@index) {
    // actual css that will be applied to column-1 if @index is 1
    width: @index * 10px; // for example
}
.columnX(3);                                   // number of columns you want
```

**Edit** (missed the `;` of `.columnX(3);` )
**Edit** Added more comments

All this should give the result :

```
.column-3 {
    width: 30px;
}
.column-2 {
    width: 20px;
}
.column-1 {
    width: 10px;
}
```

Comment: no sorry, im just not understanding :( does this allow me to do what i am asking in my question?

Comment: @user1486367 yes  it does. Just modify the number of columns and the `actual css` that you want

Comment: Heads up that `(~".column-@{index}")` will give an error. Also `.columnX(0)` isn't necessary, thanks to the guard

Answer (score 0):

This is essentially the same as @sherbrow's answer, but a little more concise and doesn't error. Consider this a long explanatory comment to support his correct answer - it's just a lot more than fits in a comment!

You'll use a [LESS loop](http://lesscss.org/features/#loops-feature) mixin like this as an intermediate helper, and then call it specifying the number of classes you want to generate. Here's how to do `.column-1`, `.column-2`, and `.column-3`. If say you wanted to go up to four columns: just do `.columns(4)` instead of `.columns(3)` [line 9]. To go up to five columns, just do `.columns(5)`.

```less
1    // we'll call this if we want to build columns
2    .columns(@i) when (@i > 0) {
3      .column-@{i} {
4        .col(@i)
5      }
6      .columns(@i - 1)
7    }
8    // for example, here we build columns 1-3
9    .columns(3);
```

which will compile to the result of

```less
.column-1 {.col(1)}
.column-2 {.col(2)}
.column-3 {.col(3)}
```

(Your question assumes there's already a mixin `.col(@x)` so I'm assuming that too. See **4** for how to skip that extra step.)

Here's what's happening:

1. The whole first chunk [lines 1-7] just sits there until called.
2. `.columns(3)` [line 9] sends us to the `.columns(@i)` mixin [line 2], assigning the variable `@i` the value `3`.
3. Because `@i` (3) is greater than 0 [line 2], we satisfy the [guard](http://lesscss.org/features/#mixin-guards-feature) and are allowed past the `{` [line 2].
4. `.column-@{i} {...}` [lines 3-5] is what this mixin will output.

   - `@i` is 3, so the output will be `.column-3 {.col(3)}`
   - the syntax `@{i}` is used to insert the variable's value as a string
   - If you don't need to use `.col(@x)` anywhere else, you could also just drop styles in here directly, e.g. (a là @sherbrow) `.column-@{i} {width: @i * 10px}`
5. *And then the loop*: after compiling lines 3-5, call this mixin again but with a different value [line 6]: `.columns(@i - 1)` ==> `.columns(3 - 1)` ==> `.columns(2)`.
6. Back to the top [line 2]: `@i`, now 2, is greater than zero, so we're allowed in. output `.column-2 {.col(2)}` (where `.col(2)` is immediately compiled, so your compiled CSS actually reads `.column-2 { the.col(2)styles }`)
7. And keep outputting and looping until `@i` isn't greater than 0 (i.e. stop after `.columns(1)`).